# Room Reservation Set-up

Tags: 2010, calendar

I am looking for a solution that I can create from scratch.  I don't have SharePoint Designer access.  Is there a YouTube Video or instructions to create a Room Reservation System in SharePoint 2010 from scratch.  Currently, when I create a calendar, I have these options that are already created:

Attendees-  Person or Group
Category - Choice Event
Check Double Booking - Check Double Booking
Description - Multiple lines of text Event
End Time - Date and Time Event
Free/Busy - Free/Busy
Location - Single line of text Event
Resources - Resources
Start Time - Date and Time Event
Title - Single line of text Event

Any guidance?

Comment: Try this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-reservation-of-resources-in-a-calendar-0bdb58b9-db48-4c9f-b3f4-b2052f0576bc?CorrelationId=65e10f6f-85f2-4fd4-ab9c-a387d457bd2b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA101810595

Comment: That worked well.  Is there a way to create a workflow on the calendar where the user will submit a request and it will go to the scheduler to book the room?

Comment: Well I thought you said you don't have access to SharePoint designer so that removes the ability to make something specific work for you. The alternative is to leverage the built in email alerts to accomplish notifications for users who need to monitor the items in the calendar. Also keep in mind that filtered views can be used for things like status updates that can also be sent though email alerts. Do some experimenting and see if you can find something that works for you. Otherwise having someone with admin / SharePoint designer would be another way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following Steps:

1- Click the Site Action menu and then click Site Settings.

2- Under Site Actions, click Manage site features.

3- Activate Group Work Lists.

4- In the calendar, in the ribbon, click the Calendar tab, and then click List Settings.

5- On the List Settings page, click Title, description, and navigation.

6- On the General Settings page, in the Group Calendar Options section, set Use this calendar for Resource Reservation to Yes, and then click Save.

7- Click the Site Actions menu and then click View All Site Content.

8- On the All Site Content page, in the Lists section, click Resources.

9- On the Resources page, click Add new item.

10- In the Resources dialog, type the Name for the resource, add an optional descriptions, and then click Save.

11- From the Resources list, in the ribbon, point to New Item, click the down arrow, and then click Resource Group.

12- In the Resources – New Item dialog box, do the following:

```
  A- Type the Name for the group, such as Conf Rooms.

  B- Select the resources you want to add to the group and click Add. You can hold        down the CTRL key to select multiple resources at the same time.

  C- Type an optional description for the group.

  D- Click Save .
```